# Modern SharePoint Web Part - Remove Horizontal Scroll bar

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, document-library, column, modern-experience

I have a Document Library web part on my modern page in which I'd only like the users to see 4 of the 7 columns.  I would normally hide the extra three columns, but due to a JSON script, they have to be visible.  So my thinking is that If I can remove the horizontal scroll bar, the users won't know those extra 3 columns are there.

Is there a way to remove the horizonal scroll bar on a Modern Document Library Web Part?  I have a Modern Script Editor Web Part I could use if this task is doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding below CSS on your page:

```
<style>
    div[data-automation-id^='detailsListContainer']:hover {
        overflow-x: hidden !important;
    }
</style>
```

---

**Note**: DOM manipulation & CSS customizations are **not recommended** by Microsoft and some of your customization may break if Microsoft changes HTML element id/classes in new release updates.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  This worked perfectly to remove the horizontal scroll bar, but I do still need the vertical scroll bar visible.  Is it possible to only remove the horizontal scroll bar?

Comment: Change `overflow` to `overflow-x`. Check updated answer.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks!!