# How can I enable horizontal Scroll bars in the Modern SharePoint List Web part for SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, list-view, modern-experience, sitepages

A user has just pointed out to me that there is no horizontal (x) scrollbar available in the list web part on a modern sharepoint page. This means that there are hidden columns to the right that you cannot see. If you view the list itself, then you can use the browser's horizontal scrollbar to scroll all the columns.

In contrast, the vertical i.e. y scrollbar in the modern list web part is available.

Has it always been like this? Is there a customization I can make via CSS/JS to enable the x scrollbar?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/297508/horizontal-scrollbar-missing-in-sharepoint-online-modern-list?rq=1) and [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293987/modern-sharepoint-web-part-remove-horizontal-scroll-bar). Let me know if it helps!

Comment: I have already reviewed those links and neither help. If I use the expand button on the page it doesn't reveal the horizontal scroll bar. This happens with a brand new SP Site and a new list WP. I have even tried it in a different tenant with the same behaviour. I have tried with both Chrome and Edge latest versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has just started working for us. Very odd. I had tried:

- two different tenants
- Guest Mode to exclude cache
- Hard reload to exclude cache
- Different client machines
- Mobile browser
- Edge Browser
- Chrome Browser
- Manipulating the CSS using overflow-x

and all of these did not show the horizontal scroll bar.

Now today it has suddenly appeared for me and other users. I suspect a change on the back-end as I don't recall seeing a browser update but its hard to say.

Comment: Yes, I think the issue was at Microsoft end and now they have resolved it.

Comment: Thanks for responding.